# Android library refuses to create R.java except when built as com.android.application

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-library, aar

I have a gradle project and am trying to build an Android library with assets and distribute it as an AAR file. However, I can only get the R.java file to generate when I use

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

and then it will only generate APK files which won't work for distribution. However, using the "correct"

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

refuses to generate the R.java file so none of my code compiles.

I am using Android Studio 1.2.1 but it refuses to build from command-line or from within the IDE so I think it is irrelevant.

I have tried rebuilding, cleaning, ensuring my XML files are not broken, deleting unused res folders, am not using custom attrs, tried multiple versions of the build tools/gradle/android api version as in other related questions. I also tried moving stuff between an app and library and yet it still fails.

Here is my project AND library build.gradle file

project gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.0'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

library gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}

//apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            buildConfigField "String", "URL_BASE", "\"http://10.0.3.2:3000\""
        }
        staging {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField "String", "URL_BASE", "\"http://10.0.3.2:3000\""
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField "String", "URL_BASE", "\"http://10.0.3.2:3000\""
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.1.2'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.8'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.7'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.1.1'
    }

    // Espresso
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:+')

    // Robolectric
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.1'

    // TODO: requires special build of robolectric right now. working on this...
    testCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4') {
        exclude module: 'classworlds'
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact-manager'
        exclude module: 'maven-error-diagnostics'
        exclude module: 'maven-model'
        exclude module: 'maven-project'
        exclude module: 'maven-settings'
        exclude module: 'plexus-container-default'
        exclude module: 'plexus-interpolation'
        exclude module: 'plexus-utils'
        exclude module: 'wagon-file'
        exclude module: 'wagon-http-lightweight'
        exclude module: 'wagon-provider-api'
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a few related QAs, could you check these to see if they resolve your issue? http://stackoverflow.com/q/7384238, http://stackoverflow.com/q/3432649, http://stackoverflow.com/q/9994940, http://stackoverflow.com/q/16566053.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. Unfortunately, I did read those and none of them seemed to help. It seems directly tied to usage of library versus app android plugin (or at least that makes the R file generate versus not). I don't have any broken xmls files or custom attrs, cleaned and rebuilt etc. None of these seem to help :(

Comment: Do you have tasks named like `process<proj_name><build_variant>Resources` in the `gradle` tab in the Android Studio after you synced the gradle files?

Comment: Where is the "gradle tab" ? When I run gradlew tasks I don't see any that start with process.

Comment: I have a library project building under Android Studio 1.2. The buildscript block in the library's build.gradle looks a bit suspicious. In my project all  repository configuration is in the project build.gradle. You also have a repositories block under dependencies. At least one of those is redundant.  I'm not at all confident either of those relates to your error though.  What's the command you are running? And what error output is it giving you? `./gradlew assembleDebug` generates an app-debug.aar for me.

Comment: I think @jayatubi means the "Gradle Console" window, you should see some lines like: `:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE`
`:app:generateDebugResources`
`:app:packageDebugResources`

Comment: @jayatubi I do see :app:processReleaseResources and unfortunately I still don't see an R file.

Comment: @gleenn try to double click that task to see if you could get any useful infomation

Answer (score 0):

I finally realized that the R.java file for the main project was in fact including the correct id's but I was getting a confusing error message leading me to believe it wasn't properly there about non-final values in Butterknife annotations. Gradle unfortunately wasn't giving me an error I could understand